# jQuery Plugins not working with Angular Router (Animsition)

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, ngroute, animsition

I'm trying to get the Animsition plugin working in an Angular project. 
**The loader is stuck and the view doesn't load.**

The jQuery plugin is in a directive, and works as separate HTML files without Angular routing. But I want to get it to work WITH Angular Router.

// In the directive, defaults were:

```
loadingParentElement : 'body',
overlayParentElement : 'body',
```

(and it worked fine without router + separate full html files with head/body/script tags to sources. But as separate views, I changed each view to have parent main elements, assuming they acted as parent body elements. But still didn't work.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
  })
   .when('/work', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/work.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

// the directive 
app.directive('ngAnimsition', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'model': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var $animsition = $(elem);
      $animsition.animsition({
        inClass: 'fade-in',
        outClass: 'fade-out',
        inDuration: 1500,
        outDuration: 800,
        linkElement: '.animsition-link',
        loading: true,
        loadingParentElement: 'main', //animsition wrapper element
        loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
        loadingInner: '', // e.g '<img src="loading.svg" />'
        timeout: false,
        timeoutCountdown: 5000,
        onLoadEvent: true,
        browser: [ 'animation-duration', '-webkit-animation-duration'],
        overlay : false,
        overlayClass : 'animsition-overlay-slide',
        overlayParentElement : 'main',
        transition: function(url) { 
          window.location.href = url;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Getting Animsition jQuery + Angular Router</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/animsition/animsition.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

      <!-- ng-router -->
      <div ng-view></div>

      <!-- tried below, but only does animsition on first load, not changing between views -->
      <!-- <div ng-animsition class="animsition">
           <!-- <div ng-view></div>
      <!-- </div>

      <!-- jquery -->
      <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/animsition/jquery.animsition.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Angular -->
      <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular/angular-router.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Partial home.html

```
<main>
    <div ng-animsition class="row container animsition">
        <nav>
            <a ng-href="#/" class="active animsition-link">Home</a>
            <a ng-href="#/work" class="animsition-link">Work</a>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Partial work.html

```
<main>
    <div ng-animsition class="row container animsition">
        <nav>
            <a ng-href="#/" class="animsition-link">Home</a>
            <a ng-href="#/work" class="active animsition-link">Work</a>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1>Work</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Is it solved yet? are you using any admin template beneath it?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem also, and i make it work by using this code, you can tried it

```
    transition: function(url){ 
        if(url){
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else{   
            location.reload();
        }
    }
```